# Best option to store content in communities

Tags: community, content

Please advise what is the best option in salesforce to store content like case studies, FAQs, help articles, training manuals, training video, user guides and this stuff should be available in Salesforce Communities.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects and Visualforce pages can be used across Communities. Most of what you're asking for (articles, training manuals, training videos, user guides, FAQs) seems like it would fit nicely into Salesforce Knowledge.